# Trouble aligning DIVs on horizontal plane

Tags: html, css

I'm on Win XP but this problem occurs on Firefox, IE, and Google Chrome.  I want to align two DIVs on the same horizontal plane.  I want the div on the left to occupy 24% of the screen and the div on the right to occupy the rest.  Everything looks fine when my browser is maximized, but when I click the resize button to make the window smaller, the two DIVs are no longer on the same plane.  The top of the right DIV appears beneath the bottom edge of the left DIV (the left boundary of the right DIV is still correctly aligned just after the right boundary of the left div).

How can I make both DIVs appear on the same horizontal plane, even when the window is not maximized?  Here is the HTML I'm using ...

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="logo.gif"/>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div id="contents">
        <div class="categoryPanel"></div>
        <div class="productDetailsPanel"></div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS ...

```
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 63px;
background-color: #333366;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
}

.categoryPanel {
height: 600px;
width: 24%;
float: left;
margin: 10px 5px 0px 0px;
background-color: green;
}

.productDetailsPanel {
height: 600px;
border-color: #BBBBBB;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
float: right;
margin: 10px 10px 0 5px;
}
```

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `.productDetailsPanel`, remove `float: right` and add `overflow: hidden`, job done; it's exactly what you asked for.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/KjZ8Q/

The reason `overflow: hidden` helps in this case is not obvious, [read this](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).

Answer (score 2):

One way to *kind of* achieve the layout you want is to stop floating `.productDetailsPanel`, and give it a left margin of `25%` (i.e. the width of `.categoryPanel`, plus spacing between them). (You’ll also want to remove the top margin on `.categoryPanel`.)

- http://jsfiddle.net/uSbAs/

But that does mean the spacing between your columns will be defined as a percentage of the `.container`, rather than a fixed number of pixels.

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to take up the entire space you would need to either fill it with something or provide a width.  I've create a jsfiddle to show the results.  Essentially I modified the `.productsDetailsPanel` by adding a `width: 75%;` removing the `float:right;` and modifying your `margin: 10px 0 0 0;`

Here is the new css for `.productsDetailsPanel`

```
.productDetailsPanel {
height: 600px;
width: 75%;
border-color: #BBBBBB;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
margin: 10px 0px 0 0px;
float: left;
background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhoenig/qXvag/

Comment: In your fiddle the red box jumps below the green one just like he says in his problem when the width of the window is shrunk.

Answer (score 0):

This could work (float: left):

```
.productDetailsPanel {
height: 600px;
border-color: #BBBBBB;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
float: left;
margin: 10px 10px 0 5px;
}
```